# Display "values" or "description" of Value Map in Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am using a geopackage with a number of tables, some of which I have added in a Value Map to the fields.  The value map is to ensure consistent entry of codes to the data to comply with a specified schema by the client.

When editing via the Attribute Table, I would like to be able to flip between displaying either the "Value" or the "Description".

The reason is that if I have a few edits the drop-down list of "Descriptions" is handy.  However, if I want to use the update bar at the top of the table to do a bulk edit (eg Update All), I can't recall the corresponding "values" and it creates errors if I get it incorrect.

Is there a way to flip the display of the attribute table so that it alternates between the two options (values or description)?

My usage is the creation of work as executed data.  I convert the surveyors' information into GIS and then add attributes to it.  Initially, I would do a "bulk" update of all bars (using the "values") to get the information say 90% correct, and then use the "Descriptions" to fine-tune the remaining features.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options if you are prepared to use PyQGIS.

For example, you can capture the details of the Value Map in a variable and then switch the attribute form to a Range (ie values) using the following code:

```
vl = iface.activeLayer() # Assuming layer is selected
fld_idx = vl.fields().lookupField('Name') # Replace Name with your field
v_map = vl.editorWidgetSetup(fld_idx).config()
vl.setEditorWidgetSetup(fld_idx, QgsEditorWidgetSetup('Range',{}))
```

Assuming you are still in the same QGIS session, you can then switch the form back to the saved Value Map using the following code:

```
vl.setEditorWidgetSetup(fld_idx, QgsEditorWidgetSetup('ValueMap', v_map))
```

This adapts some code from:
[Use PyQGIS to load Value Map against attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456730/use-pyqgis-to-load-value-map-against-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a column invisible by editing its widgets in Layer Properties > Attributes Form

More info: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#edit-widgets